# OpenCascade ErrorStatus

Tags: c++, 3d, cad, boolean-operations, opencascade

i use OpenCasCade 6.7.0.

When I Call the function ***`BRepAlgoAPI_Cut`*** and check ***`ErrorStatus()`*** i get ***`114`*** as result. Watching in documentation i got following Information:

- 0 - Ok
- 1 - The Object is created but Nothing is Done
- 2 - Null source shapes isstrong text not allowed
- 3 - Check types of the arguments
- 4 - Can not allocate memory for the DSFiller
- 5 - The Builder can not work with such types of arguments
- 6 - Unknown operation is not allowed
- 7 - Can not allocate memory for the Builder
- >100 - See the Builder's ErrorStatus

What is that Builders ErrorStatus? Where can i find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After asking this Qestion in the Official OCC Forum i got following Answer:

> Dear Hahn,
>
> thank you for your observation. In fact error status 114 of the BRepAlgoAPI_Cut means that the types of arguments do not allow to perform the CUT operation (for example, it is impossible to cut a vertex from a solid). We are planning to revise documentation on all BOA error messages. However I cannot guarantee that it will happen very soon. It depends on the availability of our internal resources.
>
> Best regards,
> Forum Supervisor